# Match contents of first file with second to generate third file

Tags: grep, string, search, text-formatting, filter

Sample data of my first file `first.txt` is below:

```
10.0.0.1,Web Server,comments1,jboss is older version,myappcode1
10.0.0.3,Web Server,comments4,httpd is latest version,myappcode15
10.0.0.7,Web Server,comments5,weblogic is old version,myappcode2
10.0.0.13,App Server,comments4,jboss is old version,myappcode15
10.0.0.2,Web Server,comments3,websphere is new version,myappcode11
.....
```

Sample data of `second.txt`

```
whatever,10.0.0.1,Web Server,date,whatever,here is JBOSS on the server,myappcode1
watever1,whatever2,10.0.0.3,here is App server,comments4,myapp17,myappcode15
whatever,10.0.0.7,check for test_WebLogic_version version,comments5,date,myappcode2
whatever,whatever,10.0.0.13,App Server,here is JBOSS,myapp17,myappcode15
whatever,whatever,whatever,10.0.0.12,Web Server,here on_windows is the latest version,whatever,
.....
```

Requirement:

I need to check if column1 & first word of fourth column of `first.txt` exists in any line of `second.txt`

Thus, `third.txt` should be

```
10.0.0.1,Web Server,comments1,jboss is older version,myappcode1
10.0.0.7,Web Server,comments5,weblogic is old version,myappcode2
10.0.0.13,App Server,comments4,jboss is old version,myappcode15
.....
```

third.txt should not contain the below two entries because:

```
10.0.0.13,App Server,comments4,jboss is old version,myappcode15  ---->  `httpd` did not match `here is App server`
10.0.0.2,Web Server,comments3,websphere is new version,myappcode11  ---->  `10.0.0.2` did not match `10.0.0.12`
```

Below is what i know but unable to put this together in a smart way.

1. Get the first  column and the first word of the fourth column in first.txt

   `cat first.txt | cut -d, -f1`  ---> Gets us first column

   `cat first.txt | cut -d, -f4 | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`  ---> Gets us first word of the fourth column
2. Grep for the column 1 and first word of fourth column in second.txt

   `cat second.txt | grep -w <first column> | grep -i 'first word of fourth column'`  ---> Need help here

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an awk script for this:

```bsh
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {
            row[tolower($0)]
            next
        }
        {
            split($4,arr," ")
            for (r in row) {
                if (r ~ tolower($1 FS) && r ~ tolower(arr[1])) {
                    print
                    next
                }
            }
        }' second.txt first.txt
```

Output:

```
10.0.0.1,Web Server,comments1,jboss is older version,myappcode1
10.0.0.7,Web Server,comments5,weblogic is old version,myappcode2
10.0.0.13,App Server,comments4,jboss is old version,myappcode15
```

We store the lines of `second.txt` as keys in the "row" accosiative array, and then we parse `first.txt` and test the selected fields with the lines into "row". `tolower()` is used to implement ignore-case matching.

**Note:** I added a modification to the above, the first matching pattern instead of the IP alone, is now `$1 FS`, meaning the IP followed by a comma. Because this is the case in both files. Without it, `10.0.0.1` would additionally match for `10.0.0.13` or similar.